# How to fill and paint over chip in powder coated aluminum chair

Tags: paint, caulking, aluminum, gap

Not sure whether due to weather/humidity changes or what, but a pretty new outdoor chair that we have has warped and cracked. It's made out of aluminum and powder coated. Whats the best remedy here?

The gap should probably be sealed - I was thinking some stretchable outdoor caulk? (Would like to avoid any metalwork as I don't have the tools for that) Pillows will be put on the spot and folks will be sitting on it so there will be quite a bit of friction.

And then painted over (just wanna cover the spot, not repaint the whole chair) Just aluminum primer and a similar color outdoor paint?

Thanks in advance!

[image: The crack]
[image: The chair]

Comment: Had water in it, the water froze and cracked it would be my first guess, given what looks like snow on the ground. Most "outdoor" furniture is not really meant to sit out through the winter.

Comment: Yes, that kind of powdercoat damage would not happen idly.  The substrate was placed under extreme stress, possibly similar to the part that overtly peeled.  Was this tubular channel (enclosed) or C-channel open on the bottom? I bet if you peel back the lost powdercoat you will find the aluminum fails inspection throughout its length.   Was the chair rated for outdoor winter use?  Does the maker have anything to say about it?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a stress fracture in the powdercoat. So covering it may only temporally fix the problem. Zinc chromate is the best primer for aluminum I would chip the section that is loose and prime (there are some paints that are for aluminum that etch as they are applied so no primer is needed) I would then paint with a matching color, it is possible the crack was from a small area that did not get fully cleaned prior to the powdercoat. You may be able to get a replacement since it is new. I would at least ask and if not prime and paint.